# Difference between Angular Js dependency Injection and a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the difference between dependency injection and a normal javascript function. Whatever Angular DI does, is something we can also do in a plain javascript function right?

Comment: Yeah, simply read the argument names from the function and resolve the dependency. of course, the dependency would need to be reachable from the resolver. Note however that you then have to somehow deal with what happens when the code is minified, which usually results in function parameter names being replaced with gibberish.

Comment: If any of these answers solved your question you can always mark it as accepted by checking the tick mark next to it

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that angular DI functions are injected by name. E.g.

`function controller($log)` is the correct way of declaring a dependency on `$http`, however `function controller($logger)` will not work since that's not the correct name for the `$log` service.

Angular dependencies get registered by the [`$provide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)  service ,though usually you will use the convenience methods that are exposed on angular [`modules`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), such as `.controller`. It's best to think of `$provide` as sort of a phonebook, you tell angular which factory/controller/... you want to match with what name. For example calling `.factory('PokemonFactory', function() { ... } )` will register `PokemonFactory` in the phonebook with the corresponding function.

The injection part is the responsibility of the [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector), you will never have to call injectable functions yourself. When you inject `PokemonFactory` in a controller for example, the `$injector` will look up `PokemonFactory` in the phonebook and get the function associated with it.

Note that in angular 1, you always have to register a factory/controller/.. with a particular named phonebook, which is represented by your module's name.

In contrast, native javascript functions arguments are resolved by order. For example `function fooBar(foo, bar)`, `foo` and `bar` can have any name you like and can be called any way you like, the only thing that matters is order. When you call `fooBar('a', false)`, `foo` will have the value of `'a'` while `bar` will have the value of `false`.

Of course you could also make injectable javascript functions yourself as well, because that's exactly what angular did.

Answer (score 0):

**Dependency Injection** : Giving an object to a function.

Rather than creating an object inside the function, you pass an object to the function.

Now the key difference is explained below with an example:

```
var Person = function(firstname, lastname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

function logPerson(){ //this function is dependent on the variable john
//if something was to change about john, it can only be changed inside this function
    var john = new Person('John, 'Doe');
    console.log(john); //will output the object
}

logPerson();
```

Same example with dependency injection:

```
var Person = function(firstname, lastname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

function logPerson(person){ //this object is passed to the function
//now this function is not dependent on how john is created
    console.log(person); //will output the object
}

var john = new Person('John, 'Doe');
logPerson(john);
```

Same is the case with Angular JS. You can inject anything to the controller function. It is not dependent on how that thing was created.

**How does angular do dependency injection?**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
    console.log($scope); //$scope is a service that is the part of core angular module
});

var searchPeople = function(firstName, lastName, height, age, occupation){
    return 'John Doe';
}

angular.injector().annotate(searchPeople); 
//if you console.log the above thing it will give you an array ["firstName", "lastName", "height","age", "occupation"]
```

Now imagine instead of firstName, you were inject $scope or anything else you are familiar with that angular uses.

Angular knows that when it sees $scope in the array, it has to create an object and pass that object to that method.